# Select analysis tool is creating an empty feature class in an arcpy stand alone script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute

I'm using select analysis to find a specific value. My program is working and I'm not getting any errors. However, the feature class that the program is creating is empty. I've double checked to make sure that the value I'm using in my where clause is in the attribute table. Below is my code.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Aliza\Desktop\GIS Programming 
Fundamentals\Final_Project\Contours"
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("SA532017.shp",
                          fields="Elevation",
                          where_clause = "Elevation = 689")
arcpy.Select_analysis("SA532017.shp", "SA532017selects.shp", '"Elevation" = 
689')
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that the search cursor does not need to be included in this program. Taking away the search cursor yields desired results.